# Binomial model in scikit-learn

Tags: predictive-modeling, scikit-learn, probability, model-selection

**Dataset**
For an E-Commerce platform, I have a lot of products (Ad_Group_ID), for each product, I have the number of people that arrive on the landing page (Clicks) ; and the number of leads = the number of people that will buy the product (Conversions). Example:

```
Date,       Ad_group_ID,Clicks,Conversions
2017-08-17, product1,   10,    1
2017-08-18, product1,   100,   10
2017-08-17, product2,   5,     0
2017-08-18, product2,   50,    5
```

**Goal**
I want to predict the number of leads

**Mathematical Model**
I imagine this is going to follow a binomiale distribution like:
[image]

**ML-Design**
[I wrote a class BinomialePredictor](https://github.com/gobert/data-science-notebooks/blob/master/sem-marketing/leads-prediction.ipynb#L4), that will delegate to scipy.binom. The results of the evaluation are acceptable IMHO (it has been wayyyy worse with try with Stochastic Gradient Descent and so on).

**Question**
Is there a module of scikit-learn that do this kind of "Binomial regression"? I think it's very strange. Or which kind of modeling would be better fit scikit-learn

Comment: Jeff, any reason why you didn't go for linear regression?